# How to make an endless running game get gradually harder in xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm making an endless running game and i want to know how to make it gradually get harder as the user progresses. I'm using xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the speed?  Spawn more monsters/ make monsters tougher & their attacks more damaging?

A game's difficulty is defined by it's challenges, so progressively increase them.